# Cipher Puzzle posed to me by my friend

Tags: cipher

My friend recently sent me some puzzle, and it has me stumped. I'm not that good (garbage, actually) at cipher puzzles, so was hoping if anyone could help me out with it.

It is..

> "General O has stolen the portal to the Blob World!
>
> Help us to take it back!
> The key to activating it is 1"

Hint:

> Three steps. The second step is simpler than you think. Think simpler.

How do I solve it?

Comment: How will i be certain that i found the correct solution?

Comment: Please read [this](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do), especially as this cipher requires three steps. How will we know if our first step is correct?

Comment: 0 and 1 look binary to me. Maybe the "blob world" ist a videogame?